# Can someone explain why sed behaves that way when doing 'sed x file.txt'?

Tags: linux, sed

I just found that if you do use sed in the following way it will output the file's contents. why would it do that or why does it behave that way?

example:

```
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ cat foxsocks.txt  
red fox in red sox
green frog in green frock
pink mouse in pink trouse
blue fly in blue tie
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ sed x foxsocks.txt

red fox in red sox
green frog in green frock
pink mouse in pink trouse
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$
```

so you can see that it does output the contents of the file except for the last line. This is a question just out of curiosity.

Comment: According to the man page: "If no `-e`, `--expression`, `-f`, or `--file` option is given, then the first non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret."  And `x`: "Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern space" which I guess ends up delaying output of lines, resulting in the leading empty line and the dropping of the last line.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes. I just played around a bit more and if you use other chars e.g. d, g, p or n instead then the output behaviour changes. e.g. for p it will output all lines twice. But not I'm not clear what the mechanism is and what it is good for if it is by intention.

Comment: Was looking briefly through `info sed` but unfortunately it looks like the section 6.2 on "Hold and Pattern Buffers" is only a "TODO" placeholder.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score -2):

So looks like this is all as intended. I just picked a the char x and it has special meaning. so do other chars like p,g,n etc. similar to the usual options your have.
also as Daniel mentioned the first argument after sed is treated as script (if not one of the described options e.g. -e )
So you could use the above if you just want to modify specific whole lines or similar I guess.

a few examples:

```
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ sed 2q foxsocks.txt
red fox in red sox
green frog in green frock
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$
```

```
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ sed 2x foxsocks.txt
red fox in red sox

pink mouse in pink trouse
blue fly in blue tie
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ sed 3x foxsocks.txt
red fox in red sox
green frog in green frock

blue fly in blue tie
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ sed x foxsocks.txt 

red fox in red sox
green frog in green frock
pink mouse in pink trouse
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$ sed 1x foxsocks.txt

green frog in green frock
pink mouse in pink trouse
blue fly in blue tie
╭─hacker@HLKali  ~/scripts  
╰─$
```